# Url length limits have been increased

Tags: support, status-completed

There's been some grumbling in the past about the unreliability of really ludicrously long URLs sent to the API.

We've always considered this suboptimal, but the underlying technical constraints (http.sys + IIS + .NET 3.5) made fixing this a very arduous endeavor.

Well, ardor has been endured and the API should accept any reasonable construction now.

Be aware that once you go past 100 ids all bets are off as *something* will kill such requests.  If its not the API itself, you'll probably get something unexpected back.

Also be aware that standard HTTP timeouts and the like apply, so really massive requests on expensive routes run the risk of Gateway Timeouts (not to mention whatever client side timeouts you may be imposing or have imposed upon you).

Comment: ++ pleasing customers is an admirable trait. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed.

Color me tickled pink for several reasons:

- Requests be much more efficient and the logic to manage them less complex
- The code for VectorizedIdList is still viable in cases where you have an id list greater than 100.

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/22656;23354;95810;18393;12950;23283;893;14860;6309;33708;10661;65358;5445;69307;3043;29407;70604;34509;13302;17034;53114;18936;157882;1968;34397;34211;61974;55159;13249;16076;12711;138475;69083;20860;3153;187606;1288;41661;33213;15168;18771;88656;76337;16883;224671;20862;21234;12960;24181;37213;9530;9021;105929;16417;267;203907;19563;17516;102937;5190;19068;27535;28169;179910;73070;84651;87234;13005;67;47773;75170;7714;63756;1583;70393;50742;3333;34088;3474;47529;222908;6521;126042;54680;19299;115145;100754;8817;151292;57428;276101;135152;139459;56338;93623;14065;23072;38360;615;21886?pagesize=100&jsonp=Soapi._internal._callback1

Comment: Woah. That's even longer than an OpenID return URL!

Answer (score 1):

This has been *unfixed*. The API is back to its old tricks only accepting around about 30 ids.

Comment: umm... click the test case above. looks like it is un-unfixed. or de-unfixed.

Comment: Awh what a headache, that URL didn't work literally 5 minutes ago

Comment: Actually, click on it a few times, sometimes you get HTTP 400. Seems intermittent.

Comment: confirmed.  and inconsistent is more annoying than just broken ;-)

Comment: we added a new server and this requires a manual step to make this change.  url lengths are now back to "crazy long"

Comment: Thanks, this should help. My app is now failing Jon Skeet test miserably - requesting in batches of 30 :(