# Retrieving comments received by a user

Tags: discussion, comments

I want to retrieve all comments directed *to* a particular user (rather than comments posted *by* that user) within a particular time period (e.g. last 24 hours).  I don't want just "mentions", which are easy enough, but also comments posted on their questions and answers.  This is technically possible - by retrieving a list of all posts and then fetching comments for each of those posts.  However, when [certain users](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) have posted ~12.5k answers on one site, it becomes very inefficient (~125 requests if the [limit is 100 IDs per request](https://stackapps.com/questions/1170/url-length-limits-have-been-increased)) to retrieve what might be only one or two comments.

Is there some better solution that I have missed or this the only option we have at the moment?

Answer (score 2):

You can request a user's questions and answers, and include `comments=true` as part of the query.  This will include all of the comments for the post in question.  This query is also limitable via the `sort=activity` and `min={24 hours ago}` fields.  Union those comments with the ones from `users/{id}/mentioned` with the same `sort` and `min` fields, and you should have all the relevant comments, no?  Or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Thanks, that would probably get most of the comments.  However, as far as I am aware, the last activity date of a post is not updated when a comment is posted.  So if I posted an answer 2 months ago and somebody posted a comment on it 1 hour ago, I don't think I'd find this comment using the approach you describe.